# Get parent route params from a lazy loaded route component

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to get the parent route params in a lazy loaded route component, however using `activatedRoute.parent.params` does not seem to work? I have a snippet which does actually work, however it involves using a 'magic' array index number to retrieve the value....

Why is this the case and is there a *cleaner* method in which I don't have to retrieve an array value (`this.activatedRoute.pathFromRoot[1]`)?

---

I have the following route in which I lazy load a module:

**parent.route**

```
routes:Routes = [
    {
        path: "dashboard/:id",
        component: dashboard.DashboardComponent,
        canActivate: [guard.LoggedInGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: "my-dock",
                loadChildren: 'path/child.module#Child'
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Then in the default component for `child.module` I have the following:

**child.component**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.pathFromRoot[1].params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        console.log(params); // returns {id: "123456789"}
    });

    this.activatedRoute.parent.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        console.log(params);  // returns {}
    });
}
```

---

Why can't I use `this.activatedRoute.parent.params` to get the `id` param?

Comment: can you add how does your child module route looks like? It seems you may be looking into immidiate parent, and you need to use grandparent by using `this.activatedRoute.parent.parent`, Cheers!!

Comment: @MadhuRanjan as in the url?

Comment: No, the route configuration, like you have shared for parent.route.

Comment: @MadhuRanjan ahhh yep

Comment: ahh yep as in you are going to add child routes or you were looking at wrong parent? :)

Comment: @MadhuRanjan I will add child routes in asap!

Answer (score 11):

Well you can access parent of parent router data. It seems a bit weird in some project structures but you can do it if you are aware of your router structure.

```
 constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute

)
this.route.parent.parent.params.subscribe( (params) => {
        console.log(params);
        this.urlKey = params['urlKey'];
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

The following methods are working perfectly in Angular-6 (may be in Angular-5, but not sure)

```
// method 1
this.activatedRoute.pathFromRoot[1].params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
    console.log(params);
});

// method 2    
this.activatedRoute.parent.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
    console.log(params);
});
```

> Q. Why can't I use this.activatedRoute.parent.params to get the id param?

A. You have not mentioned the Angular version you were using but in Angular-6 both these methods work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will need to test this. Or maybe you could provide a StackBlitz (not sure how that goes with routing though)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get this done without the `'magic' array index number` is to use a Service .

- get the Params or the URL in the parent and put them into a service.
- Access the params from the service variable in the Lazy loaded component from the service.
  Some thing like this

**ParentComponent**

```
constructor(private router : Router){
    this.service.setParams(this.router.url);//you might need to split here
    //you can also make use of Activate Route and subcribe to params
}
```

**Service**

```
params:string;

setParams(params:string){
    this.params = params;
}

getparams(){
    return this.params;
}
```

Now in child Lazyloaded component you can get the params using `service.getparams()`

Comment: This won't work if it is the entry URL. i.e. the first url navigated to when visiting the site. There won't be an opportunity to "save" this into a service.

Comment: you are telling the entry url itself is a lazy loaded one then you need to do the same as you have mentioned in the question and save it in service for the first time . there is no cleaner way for it

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue and i have tried this :

```
this.activatedRoute.parent.parent
```

it's working very well with me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `paramsInheritanceStrategy`. See https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions